# If i edit a torrent's downloaded file(s) will they count as a seed?

Tags: itunes, bittorrent, utorrent

Like if I edit a file's ID3 on itunes or if I change the contents of a file. Put simply if I modify a downloaded torrent's files in any way.

Comment: I'm guessing no, because any modification you do to the file will result in a completely different hash.

Comment: No. If you change the contents of a torrent the it becomes an entirely new torrent and would need to be republished

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be **no**, since a seed is someone who has 100% of the file and is uploading it.